# How to escape ` (tick) in inline javascript code?

Tags: coffeescript

```
inlineJs = `
  function(){ return 'It won`t compile' }
`
```

This code wont compile because of **`** (tick) in inline javascript code - how I can escape it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inlineJs = `
  function(){ return 'It won\`t compile' }
`

alert inlineJs()
```

simply escaped by `\`